# Modal not displaying even though cookie is cleared

Tags: jquery, cookies

My modal is not appearing for some reason I have put the fact that if the cookie does exist the popup will not show but I cleared my cookies on my development machine and its still not showing there are no errors in the console and my console log does not get hit I am running this in visual studio.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    // Delayed Modal Display + Cookie On Click
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

            // we want to trap the user closing the popup and we also set the cookie expiery here to seven days.
            $.cookie('galgormgrouppopup', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
        })

        // If no cookie with our chosen name (e.g. no_thanks)...
        if ($.cookie("galgormgrouppopup") == null) {

            // Show the modal, with delay func.
            $('#myModal').appendTo("body");

            $("#myModal").appendTo("form:first");

            function show_modal() {
                console.log('does my modal get called');

                $('#myModal').modal();
                console.log('does my modal get called after');

            }

            // Set delay func. time in milliseconds
            window.setTimeout(show_modal, 10000);
        }




    });
</script>
```

This is my modal code which as a .net update panel in it had no issues before but seems to be not displaying.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:left;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span  style="display:none;" class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" align="center">10% Off Your Frist Order!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <img src="/index-images/galgormgroupgraphic.png" width="100%" alt="10% Off First Order" />
            <div style="float:left">
           *excludes Furniture and Catering Equipment </div>
           <div ></div>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter Email for Discount"  CssClass="emailField"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />


              <asp:label runat="server" id="lblVoucher"  style="font-size:16px;"></asp:label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblblerror" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                <asp:button runat="server" CausesValidation = "false" class="btn btn-primary  "   
                 OnClick="btnNewGetVoucher_Click"
               ID ="btnNewGetVoucher"    style="background-color:#007B78;color:white;align-self:center;height:55px;width:100%"  text="Get Voucher Code" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- Make sure to include the 'nothanks' class on the buttons -->

       </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7hb37hw/

Sorry if my jsfiddle is not setup correct quite new to using it !

Comment: Your fiddle is missing the script that provides `$.cookie` You can add it as an External Resource via the side panel.

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean ?. Sorry do you mean I need a resource to allow cookies on the fiddle?

Comment: $.cookie is not part of core jQuery, you must embed an additional script if you want to use it.

Comment: _“I am running this in visual studio”_ - sure that’s not part of the issue maybe? Always test in a real web browser, calling your pages via HTTP/HTTPS ... everything else is likely to produce unrealistic test conditions sooner or later.

Comment: What I meant was running in visual studio but testing on a local browser on local host

Comment: Are you getting any error in the `browser` console?

Comment: @Cbroe I have search to look for how to add $ cookie can you explain please

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - but that is outdated, and has been superseded by https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie - the latter uses a slightly different syntax though.